# could not find method in activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an android app where I have a landscape view with two fragments. The left sided fragment has a list, and the right sided fragment a regular view displaying information. Right Now I have a view where I have two buttons "add contact" and "edit contact". When I click the "add contact" button a successfully add on another fragment where the user can input contact information.  Once completed the user clicks a "save" button and that is where I get an error.

in my SHContactOverviewActivty class I have the following piece of code:

```
public void addContact(View view) {

    SHConfigureContactFragment shConfigContactFrag = new SHConfigureContactFragment(); 
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    ft.replace(R.id.contentPanel, shConfigContactFrag); 

    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();


}
```

which is tied to the following XML called sh_fragment_contact_info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addContactButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/sh_button_selector"
                android:onClick="addContact"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:text="Add Contact"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_take_survey_button"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This successfully adds the following fragment on top, and I can move back and forth between the views. The class SHConfigureContactFragment as follows:

```
public class SHConfigureContactFragment extends Fragment{

    private EditText name; 
    private EditText description; 
    private EditText primaryNumber; 
    private EditText secondaryNumber; 
    private EditText email; 
    private EditText skype; 
    private Byte[] photo; 

    private Boolean isDualPane; 
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager; 
    private SHContactMenuFragment menuFragment; 
    private SHConfigureContactFragment contactFragment; 

    private DatabaseControllerLibrary controller; 
    private Contact contact;
    private SHPatient patient; 
    private int patientId; 
    public  View rootView; 


    public int selectedIndex; 

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            this.selectedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_INDEX");
            this.contact = (Contact) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("CONTACT");
        }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("CONTACT", contact);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        controller = SHController.getInstance(getActivity());
        patient = ((SHController) controller).getPatient(); 
        patientId = patient.getId(); 

    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sh_fragment_contact_edit, container, false);
        return rootView; 
    }

    private void setupTextFieldsByContact(Contact contact) {
        name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editContactName);
        description = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editContactDescription);
        primaryNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editContactPrimaryNumber);
        secondaryNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editContactSecondaryNumber);
        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editContactEmail);
        skype = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editContactSkype);

        if (contact != null) {
            name.setText(contact.getName());
            description.setText(contact.getDescription());
            primaryNumber.setText(contact.getPrimaryNumber());
            secondaryNumber.setText(contact.getSecondaryNumber());
            email.setText(contact.getEmail());
            skype.setText(contact.getSkype());
        }
    }

    //Listener for saveContact 'onClick' in sh_fragment_contact_edit.xml for the "Save" button
    public void saveContact(View view){
        boolean isValid = true;

        // assigning IDs based on how many contacts are created. no reused IDs son!
        int id = controller.getContactsCount();
        id++;

        String newName = name.getText().toString().trim();
        String newDescription = description.getText().toString().trim();
        String newPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String newSecondaryNumber = secondaryNumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String newEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String newSkype = skype.getText().toString().trim();


        if(newName.length()==0 || newName.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
            name.setText("");
            isValid = false;
        }
        if(newPrimaryNumber.length()==0) {
            primaryNumber.setText("");
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (isValid){
            Contact updatedContact;
            ContactConfiguration updatedConfiguration;

            if (contact != null){
                id = contact.getId();
            }

            updatedContact = new Contact(id, newName, newDescription, newPrimaryNumber, newSecondaryNumber, newEmail, newSkype, null);

            updatedConfiguration = new ContactConfiguration(patientId, patientId, false, updatedContact);

            if (contact == null){
                controller.addContact(updatedContact, patientId);

            }
            else{
                controller.updateContact(updatedContact, patientId);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

The method I am concerned with here is the onSave(View v) where I have code to add a contact to a database that I have created.

This view is attached to an XML called sh_fragment_contact_edit where I have the following:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addContactButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sh_button_selector"
            android:onClick="saveContact"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:text="Save Contact"
            android:textColor="@color/text_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_take_survey_button"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I know this is a lot to look at but I think it is all needed to explain the problem. When The views all load correctly, but once I click the "save" button I get the following error:

**Could not find a method saveContact(View) in the activity class SHContactOverviewActivty, for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'addContactButton'**

My question is, do I need to have this saveContact(View view) method inside SHContactOverviewActivty even though I only have the saveContact() (The fragment where I intend to save the contact information) in SHConfigureContactFragment?

I do not see why I would need it in SHContactOverviewActivty when that is not the fragment where I call it from.

Again, sorry for lengthiness, but I have just been stuck on this so long, looking at so many different posts that I thought I needed to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's looking for `saveContact()` in the Activity, not the Fragment. I think you will have to use `Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){onClick()...});` in your fragment's onCreateView by looking up the button's ID.

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public onClick(View v){
        //Code
    });
```

I highly recommend this method for normal development, as changing stuff in layouts is tedious if you have different densities. Furthermore, it's possible to reassign clicklisteners to buttons, or turn them null, without mush hassle.

Edit, for your actual question: The layout is automatically limited to only interact the `android:onClick` with the parent activity, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents). This is an Android limitation, likely because checking backwards is expensive. Besides, what if you have fragments inside fragments inside fragments? Seems like a messy thing to code. You could have many fragment scopes to check in.

Comment: Thank you for response, so the first line in this snippet opens up when the addContactButton is clicked in activity, and then will use the saveContact() method in my fragment?

Comment: No, the `saveContact()` method should be removed after implementing the `onClickListener`, and you should remove the `android:onClick` attribute from the XML layout. Put the code from `public void saveContact(View view)` where //code is in my snippet.

Comment: Further clarification: you should really only add clicklisteners from the Java class that inflates the view you want to do an action. You should `findViewById(R.id.addContactButton)` from the activity or fragment that directly inflates `sh_fragment_contact_edit.xml`. Any buttons created in the activity should have their `clickListeners` set inside the activity. This isn't really a limitation, but it's just best practice.

Comment: ok so I do Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addContactButton); and the rest of what you said. The issue is that I get nullPointerexceptions which are causes I think becuase onCreate gets called before where I inflate the rootview in onCreateView

Comment: Apologies, the flow in **`onCreateView`** is `View v = inflater.inflate(...)`, then `Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);`, then finally `button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {});`.